# Prevent Grails input tags from adding id attributes

Tags: html, grails, groovy, gsp

I noticed that some of the Grails tags for generating input elements (`g:textField`, `g:hiddenField`, and some others) automatically set the id attribute of the generated HTML tag equal to the name attribute, unless the id attribute is explicitly given.

Is there any way to use those custom tags to produce an HTML tag without an id attribute? I tried setting the id attribute to an empty string but the generated code had the id set to the name.

I know I can do this with custom tags but I am wondering if there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be possible. The source code of the `FormTagLib.groovy` class shows that there is a flag that decides whether to write `id` attributes identical to the name if an id was not given. Unfortunately it is turned *on* and not configurable from outside. See the following code:

First, we have the source of `g:textField` which calls `fieldImpl`

```
def textField = { attrs ->
    attrs.type = "text"
    attrs.tagName = "textField"
    fieldImpl(out, attrs)
}
```

The method `fieldImpl` ([full source available on Github](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/FormTagLib.groovy)) calls `outputAttributes`. Note the third parameter which is `true`

```
 def fieldImpl(out, attrs) {
    resolveAttributes(attrs)
    out << "<input type=\"${attrs.remove('type')}\" "
    outputAttributes(attrs, out, true)
    out << "/>"
}
```

outputAttributes looks like this (abbreviated):

```
void outputAttributes(attrs, writer, boolean useNameAsIdIfIdDoesNotExist = false) {
    attrs.remove('tagName') // Just in case one is left
    attrs.each { k, v ->
      ...
    }
    if(useNameAsIdIfIdDoesNotExist) {
        outputNameAsIdIfIdDoesNotExist(attrs, writer)
    }
}
```

This method calls `outputNameAsIdIfIdDoesNotExist...` which will generate the actual id. As `outputAttribues` always receives `true`, nothing can be done to overwrite it.

Comment: This is not the answer I wanted to see but it answered my question and it is helpful. Thank you.